# In AEM SiteAdmin, how can I use 'name' instead of 'title' in the left navigation pane?

Tags: aem

From the SiteAdmin view, the "Websites" tab in the left-hand navigation pane displays the "Title" attribute from nodes, but sorts according to the "name" attribute. Which file(s) would need to be edited to output the "name" value in that pane instead of "title"?

Comment: Can you please leave a use case why you want to show nodes with `title` attribute in siteadmin.

Just to correct you, the pages are sorted according to the publish date in siteadmin which is `jcr:created` in crx/de.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  The use case is that it becomes easier for my content authors to locate the parent node they're trying to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script responsible for rendering siteadmin is - `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/SiteAdmin.js`

If you look at line number 340, it has configuration like -

[image: siteadmin.js snippet]

The call `/bin/wcm/siteadmin/tree.json` is handled by `SiteAdminTreeServlet` which generates the JSON used in rendering the tree (and sorting it). You could overlay this to use your own Servlet that gives the result in the sorted order of field you need (not recommended unless you know the nitty–gritty of this servlet).

If you still want to proceed with the changes you need to do two things -

1. Add configurations to disable `SiteAdminTreeServlet`, use OSGI component disable logic to achieve this or you could refer to AEM ACS Commons [here](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/osgi-disabler.html)
2. Provide your own implementation as Servlet to handle the requests to the path `/bin/wcm/siteadmin/tree` and handle json extension explicitly (path based servlet will ignore extensions).

You can try invoking this servlet as `http://localhost:4502/bin/wcm/siteadmin/tree.json?path=/content`

Comment: Thank you, Ameesha! The bounty is well deserved.

Answer (score 0):

In CQ/AEM /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/override/widgets/tree/TreeNodeUI.js script renders the left hand side of siteadmin. You can directly make a minor change in this script to display page name instead of page title in the CQ siteadmin.

[Click here to look at the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNChD.jpg)

`CQ.shared.XSS.getXSSValue(n.text.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"))` should be changed to `CQ.shared.XSS.getXSSValue(n.attributes.name.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"))` at line number 71 in /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/override/widgets/tree/TreeNodeUI.js and it works great

Comment: Please post your code in a *code block* rather than an *image*.

Comment: `CQ.shared.XSS.getXSSValue(n.text.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"))` should be changed to `CQ.shared.XSS.getXSSValue(n.attributes.name.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"))` at line number 71 in /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/override/widgets/tree/TreeNodeUI.js